# Why is mirror and subdiving co-acting wierdly?

Tags: modeling

Heres a picture. im making a body, and it seems to have flash in the middle.

[image]

Comment: Do you have faces inside where the edges connect?

Comment: CVed on the wrong question... Duplicate of this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/25964/599

Comment: maybe. ill check.

Comment: No i do not have faces inside.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get smooth surface transition with Mirror and Subdivision modifiers you have to remove the internal faces where the mirrored mesh connects.

[image]

Comment: note that extruding on the direction other than the mirror direction will create new faces there unless "clipping" is enabled.